# binary search find the element that does not repeat java

Tags: java, binary-search

```java
//package alg;
import java.io.*;

//import java.io.File;
//import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
//import java.io.InvalidCommandException;
//import java.io.NumberFormatException;
import java.util.Arrays;
//import java.util.ArrayList;
//import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

//import javax.sound.sampled.Line;

public class FindOut
{
    public static void Find(int [] Ray, int min , int max)
    {


        if(min > max)
        {
            return;
        }

        if(min == max)
        {
            System.out.println(Ray[min]);
            return;

        }

        int med = (min + max)/2;


        if(med % 2 == 0)
        {

            if(Ray[med] == Ray[med + 1])
                Find(Ray, med + 2, max);

            else
                Find(Ray, min, med);

        }

        else //if(med % 2 == 1)
        //{

            if(Ray[med] == Ray[med-1])

                Find(Ray, med + 1 , max);

            else
                Find(Ray, min, med - 1);
    //  }



    }





    public static void main(String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {

        @SuppressWarnings("resource")


        File file = new File(args [0]);

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);


                try
        {

            int[] Ray = new int [5];    

            while(scanner.hasNext())
            {

                String num = scanner.next();



                 Ray = Arrays.stream(num.split(",")).mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();


                Find(Ray,0, Ray.length-1);





            }


                //  File inputFile = new File(num);


        }
        catch(NumberFormatException ex)
        {

        }

 }
}
```

What I need is to input a file through command line and it will read the integers inside place them into an array that I send through the function to find the element that appears only once such as

> 3 , 3 ,48, 48, 65, 95, 95

It should output

> 65

But what it does is

> 3
>   3
>   48
>   48
>   65
>   95
>   95

I know its not the function I tested that with hard code and ran through the main logically step by step so can anyone explain the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is something wrong with how the file is read. It seems the code expects one line to contain the entire list of numbers. However, `Scanner` uses whitespace as the default delimiter. `Find` ends up being called once for every number in the file.

To fix it, a delimiter can be specified like so:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter(",");
```

This means there is no need for the `mapToInt` thing you were doing. Instead, I recommend you use a container from `Collections` such as `ArrayList`, and appending the number to it after conversion to an integer.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    File file = new File(args [0]);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file).useDelimiter(",");

    try {
        ArrayList<Integer> Ray = new ArrayList<>();

        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            String num = scanner.next().trim();
            Ray.add(Integer.parseInt(num));
        }

        scanner.close();
        int[] arr = Ray.stream().mapToInt(i -> i).toArray();
        Find(arr, 0, arr.length - 1);
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {

    }
}
```

Using an `ArrayList` allows it expand as needed, unlike an array, which has a fixed size. This is convenient because it means you don't have to know the amount of integers in the file ahead of time.

To keep compatibility with your `Find` function, I converted the `ArrayList` back to a normal array. However, I recommend you update your function to accept an `ArrayList`.